# Kendoui Date Picker Issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I Select Date from date picker and post data, i that i got `2014-04-11T11:43:24.803Z`.
But I want Simple date like `2014-04-11 11:43:24.80`/2014-04-11/11:43:24.80,
So please suggest me appropriate solution.

Comment: $('body').find('.k-grid').delegate(".k-datepicker", "change", function(e) {

},how to fetch datepicker value into this above code..?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here:

```
$("#request_date").kendoDatePicker({       
    parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"]
});
```

Your Code: you should try this. remove T in format.

```
$FromDate = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn(); $FromDate->field('FromDate') ->template('#= FromDate ? kendo.toString(FromDate, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") : "" #') ->headerTemplate('<b>From Date</b>') ->format('yyyy-MM-dd') ->title('FromDate');
```

For more formatting please visit:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting

Comment: This is my Schema field ---model = $schemaModel->addSchemaField('FromDate', array(), 'date');

Comment: this is my grid column --$FromDate = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
  $FromDate->field('FromDate')
     ->template('#= FromDate ? kendo.toString(FromDate, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss") : "" #')
        ->headerTemplate('<b>From Date</b>')
        ->format('yyyy-MM-dd')
        ->title('FromDate');

Comment: After selecting date it display proper date but after post it give T and Z.

Comment: IT give error--sorry for inconvience. SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '2014-04-23T12:28:41.481Z' for column 'FromDate' at row 1